# ImportError with pybrain on IPython Notebook, how does Importing work?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, importerror, pybrain

I'm trying to use pybrain in an IPython Notebook, and when I pip installed, I could import pybrain from the command line python interpreter, but not from iPython or an iPython Notebook.

I then downloaded manually to `/Users/myUserName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, cd'd into the new pybrain dir, and ran `python setup.py install`. Still I couldn't import from my IPython Notebook, although I could from my command line iPython interpreter.

I found that if I run

```
sys.path.append('/Users/myUserName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybrain')
```

in my IPython Notebook, I can import pybrain, but that seems silly to have to add the path one directory layer deeper than all the other packages.

So I guess I'm really asking, why is this case different? What do I have to do to the directory structure so I don't have to add that extra directory step into my sys.path? I'm guessing there is just some simple piece of the import process that I just don't understand.

edit: It seems to be something with the `__init__.py` file being in the nested pybrain directory. I have flattened the dir structure so there is no more nested pybrain dir and all its contents are just copied to the root dir. Hoping that doesn't cause any internal dependencies to fail.

Comment: Here's how to tell python where to look for modules: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: what is the output of `print(sys.path)`?

Comment: @Sean M, this is sys.path:
['',
 '/anaconda/lib/python27.zip',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-19.6.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/.ipython']

Comment: `whereis pip` from the command line?

Comment: `whereis pip` does nothing and moves on to the next input prompt.

`which pip` gives: /usr/local/bin/pip